# Gem::LoadError: can't activate mysql2 (< 0.5, >= 0.3.18), already activated mysql2-0.5.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I did `bundle install` and the mysql2 gem was updated from 0.4.10 to 0.5.0.

After this anything involving ActiveRecord blows up with the error in the title.

Comment: This also manifests as the error: `Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ActiveRecord only works with [specific versions](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb#L6) of mysql2.

In your Gemfile add:

```
gem 'mysql2', '< 0.5'
```

and `bundle install`.

I would also recommend adding a comment pointing to this URL so you know why the gem is pinned.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, which someone has fixed :)