# How to create migrations with specific COLLATE?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord, mysql2

I recently upgraded Ubuntu on my dev machine this included a newer version of MySQL, version 8.

As a result I had to bump the [mysql2 gem](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2) due to a segfault when running migrations. It was previously pinned to `< 0.5` due to ActiveRecord, at the time, [not being compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49407254/gemloaderror-cant-activate-mysql2-0-5-0-3-18-already-activated-mysq) with newer versions of the mysql2 gem.

The problem is that when I run migrations the schema.rb contains `create_table`'s with a `COLLATE` of `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`. This is fine locally on MySQL 8 but is not supported on our CI or production servers since they run an older version of MySQL:

```
 Mysql2::Error: Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'
```

Before upgrading to MySQL 8 the `COLLATE` was not present, just `CHARSET`:

```
-  create_table "tasks", id: :integer, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4", force: :cascade do |t|
+  create_table "tasks", id: :integer, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci", force: :cascade do |t|
```

In my database.yml I specific the encoding as `utf8mb4`, is there a way to specify the `COLLATE` too?

Answer (score 3):

You can specify `COLLATE` in database.yml:

```
adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8mb4
  collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

You can find your existing database collation as follows:

```
use my_app_production;
SELECT @@character_set_database, @@collation_database;
```

Or a specific table:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'users';
```

Incidentally when specifying the collation there is no need to bump the mysql2 gem either as the segfault goes away.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the collation:

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```